# Why is this console.log affecting my get request?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, api, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to do a get request to /tasks and as a parameter, I am sending a user email address. Then I'm trying to fetch all tasks belonging to a user. It kept not working and while debugging I realized that for some reason a specific console.log would make my code work. However, I cannot figure out why this would be the case. If I do not use this console.log it won't find a user. This is my api route:

```
app.get('/tasks', async (req, res) => {
//For some reason this console log makes it work. If I change it or take it out the code stops working.
  console.log(req.query.email.email)
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({
      $and: [{ email: req.query.email }],
    })
    if (!user) {
      throw new Error('User not found')
    }
    console.log(user.tasks)
    res.send(user.tasks)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    res.send('User not found')
  }
})
```

This is the code I am using to send the email adress:

```
export const actions = {
  async getTasks(context, userInfo = this.$cookies.get('userinfo')) {
    await this.$axios
      .$get('http://localhost:3000/api/tasks', {
        params: {
          email: userInfo.email,
        },
      })
      .then((res) => context.commit('getTaskList', res))
  },
}
```

userInfo is just an object containing some user details like first, last name and email.

Comment: Remove the try .. catch, you might get useful error messages.

Comment: Long shot but - add a timeout of 1 millisecond  instead of the console.log

Comment: How do you check that the code works? The only way `console.log(req.query.email.email)` can make it work differently is that it fails if req.query.email isn't an object, this certainly doesn't make the code work correctly. Please, narrow down the problem to either front or backend, if it's on backend, it should be reproducible with no Vue involved, and vice versa.